# How to get wxPython Installed and working in Win7?

Tags: wxpython

How to get wxPython installed and working in Win7?

I entered lots of details, but there was not enough indenting, then---

Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).

So, extremely generically, how do I get wxPython working without giving you the file I installed or the code that I tried to run?

Answer (score 4):

Go to http://wxpython.org/ and click the Download link on the left. Pick the appropriate binary that matches your version of Python (make sure you pay attention to the 32/64-bit part too). Once you have the matching version, install it. That's it. That has always worked for me on Windows XP and 7.